# (Android) More space for actionbar items still not visible?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, space

I have removed title from my ActionBar using 
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

And added 5 items to my Actionbar but i am still unable to see more than 2 in it 
and the area of title is totally unused .

How can i use it to show more items in ActionBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```